# Feymann Kac formula to solve Pde

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I Have to solve the following PDE:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2}+\dfrac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x\partial y}=0\\
F(t,x,y)=xy^2
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
My problem is the presence of the mixed derivative term and I don't have any Idea on how to manage it.
If the mixed derivative term is not present I know that I can introduce two independent brownian motion under the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ and describe the dynamics of the process $X$ and $Y$ as:
\begin{equation}
dX_t=dW_t^1\\
dY_t=dW_t^2
\end{equation}
and then apply the formula:
\begin{equation}
F(t,X_t,Y_t)=E^\mathbb{P}_t[X_TY_T^2]=E_t^\mathbb{P}[X_T]E_t^\mathbb{P}[Y^2_T]
\end{equation}
If the mixed derivative is present I know that the two process can be correlated in some ways but I'm not able to write explicit caluclations. Can someone help me?

Comment: You can combine the second derivative terms to $\frac12(∂_x+∂_y)^2F$. This means that you only need one scalar Wiener process. Or in other word, parametrizing $F(x,y)=G(x+y,x-y)$ the derivatives for the second place in $G$ cancel.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Ok I understand this idea but if I didn't recognise directly this fact is there a standard procedure to tackle the problem? In another way is there a direct approach consisting in the introduction of two brownian motions and then computing the dynamics of the two processes?

Comment: There is no stochastic PDE in this question